# turn two sql joins into a double join? possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I currently have two separate SQL JOINS. One is getting a project name and the other a class name from two different tables from the same ID.

A table called PUPILPROJECT holds an ID, projectID and ClassID which are also in a PROJECT table with the PROJECT name and a CLASS table with the CLASS name.

Is there a way of doing this with a single query? All help is much appreciated!

```
//GET PROJECT NAME
$getproject = mysql_query("SELECT project_name FROM projects JOIN pupilproject USING     (project_id) WHERE pupil_project_id = '".$id."'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getproject)) {
$thisproject = $row['project_name'];
}

//GET PROJECT CLASS NAME
$classname = mysql_query("SELECT class_name FROM class JOIN pupilproject USING     (class_id) WHERE pupil_project_id = '".$id."'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($classname)) {
$pclass = $row['class_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following SQL in your code:

```
"SELECT project_name, class_name
FROM pupilproject
LEFT JOIN projects USING (project_id)
LEFT JOIN class USING (class_id)
WHERE pupil_project_id = '".$id."'"
```

Comment: no luck. are there specific requirements for the database?